# Application of Set Notation to Show that One Event Contains another Event

Tags: probability

There are two groups of people,  $Q$ and $P$ in a park.

Let,

$Q_{k}$ be $\textit{at least $'k'$ people in the group Q}$

$P_{k}$ be $\textit{at least $'k'$ people in the group P}$

> If $Q$ has more people than $P$, represent the occurrence using the events listed and set operators.

If $P$ has at least $p$ people in the group, then we have $P_p$. Given this, there must be at least $q$ people in $Q$ (i.e. $Q_{q}$) such that $q > p$ and $p,q\in \mathbb{N} $. If the $q > p$  holds, then the group $Q$ would contain the group $P$.

Therefore, we can write the occurrence as $P_{p} \subset Q_{q}$ where $q > p$ and $p,q\in \mathbb{N} $.

Is this correct?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but why does $q>p$ imply $P_p\subset Q_q$?   
Where is the term you refer to in "If the above holds"?

Comment: If q > p, then the number of people in P in less than the number of people in Q. Therefore, the event Q contains P. Here q is the least number of people in Q and p is the least number of people in P. I hope that makes some sense.

Comment: And by "if the above holds", I mean q > p.

Comment: @convex-body: How would you go about answering this question?

Comment: Sorry, deleted my earlier comments since they were wrong, but gave an aswer instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that you know [Q is bigger than P] is equiv to saying that for any n such that group P has at least n people in it, group Q has at least n+1. so
$$\text{Q is bigger than P}\iff[\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\quad P_n\Rightarrow Q_{n+1}]\iff[\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\quad P_n\subset Q_{n+1}]$$

That is not saying that for any $q>p\quad P_p\subset Q_q$ because as q gets larger, $Q_q$ gets smaller - the fact that group P has 3 people does not imply group Q has a million...